# Puma starting in single mode but not really start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins

I'm configuring Jenkins to deploy in production my rails application.

At the end of jenkings, i can see:

```
+ bin/bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.2-p95), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
* Daemonizing...
 Finished: SUCCESS
```

After the script, puma is not running ...

config/puma.rb

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count
railsenv = 'production'
directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyRailsApp'
environment railsenv
daemonize true
pidfile "/tmp/pids/puma-#{railsenv}.pid"
state_path "/tmp/pids/puma-#{railsenv}.state"
threads 0, 16
bind "unix:///tmp/my-rails-app.sock"
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
preload_app!
on_worker_boot do
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end
plugin :tmp_restart
```

What's the best way to start/restart puma with Jenkins ?